# React Functional Component Fetching User Data Doesn't Update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

I am very new to React and am working on implementing a MERN application. I'm currently implementing a simple user profile page that is supposed to display user info, however, the user info is sometimes shown and sometimes it disappears when I refresh the Profile page, even when the user is still logged in. I'm not sure what I'm missing. I'd like the info to be shown every time the user visits their profile. I'd appreciate any help and advice on what concepts should I review to understand this problem.
Here's my `Profile.js` code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from "axios";
import './Profile.css'

const Profile = () => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const getUser = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get("/api/auth", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
      },
    });
    setUser(res.data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
        <div className='profile'>
          <div>
            <img className='user-photo'
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612024638904-bda171b93c66?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NDN8fHBlcnNvbnxlbnwwfDJ8MHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60"
            />
          </div>
          <div className='user-info' >
            <div className='user-info'>
              Name: {user && user.name}
            </div>
            <div className='user-info'>
              Email: {user && user.email}
            </div>
            <div>
              <button className='user-info'>Update Profile</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

My `App.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Register from "./auth/Register";
import Login from "./auth/Login";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./components/pages/About";
import Profile from "./components/pages/Profile";
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {

    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/about' component={About} />
          <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Here's what happens when I visit the Profile page and the info is there:]

[image: And sometimes after refreshing it disappears:]

Comment: Maybe your API call does not work all the time? Try wrapping it into `try...catch...` and log the error if there is one.

Comment: @Stophface Will try that, thank you!

Comment: Also, introduce a loading state, it would help in rendering a loader and indicate that the call is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

useEffect doesnt get called before the first render